# Rails case/switch with more than one parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
<% case action_name %>
<% when 'one' %>
    <p>One</p>
<% when 'two' || 'three' %>
    <p>Two and Three</p>
<% end %>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way of using the `case` approach and performing a case with multiple parameters, like the second case on my example?

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
<% case action_name %>
<% when 'one' %>
    <p>One</p>
<% when 'two', 'three' %>
    <p>Two and Three</p>
<% end %>
```